# How do i solve this error ERROR [Error: modelWeightsID must be a number or number array. Have you wrapped yor asset paths in a require() statements?]

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on react native expo project, where i am want to load tensorflowjs model but i am having this error `ERROR [Error: modelWeightsID must be a number or number array. Have you wrapped yor asset paths in a require() statements?]`

```
const modelJson = require('../../assets/maize/model.json');
const modelWeights = require('../../assets/maize/group1-shard1of1.bin');

useEffect(() => {
    const loadModel = async () => {
      try {
        const loadedModel = await tf.loadLayersModel(
          bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights)
        );
        setModel(loadedModel);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };    
    loadModel();
  }, []);
```